# Как получить целый объект, если есть одно его свойсто?

Tags: javascript

У меня есть структура такого типа:

```
const data = {"id1": {
        "name": "Bob",
        "userId": 'userId1'
    },
    "id2": {
        "name": "jack",
        "userId": 'userId2'
    },
    "id3": {
        "name": "Sally",
        "userId": 'userId3'
    },
    "id4": {
        "name": "Billy",
        "userId": 'userId4'
    }
}
```

Если я имею только `userId`, я могу как то  получить `name`?

Comment: _структура_ на самом деле в `{`,`}` обрамлена? или как?

Comment: @Grundy да, это объект

Comment: @Grundy как можно передавать в функцию 'userId', а получать id объекта в каком находиться 'userId' ('id..') - это был бы идеальный вариант

Comment: Точно так же как в ответе, только идти надо по ключам

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const data = {
  "id1": {
      "name": "Bob",
      "userId": 'userId1'
  },
  "id2": {
      "name": "jack",
      "userId": 'userId2'
  },
  "id3": {
      "name": "Sally",
      "userId": 'userId3'
  },
  "id4": {
      "name": "Billy",
      "userId": 'userId4'
  }
}

const findById = (data, id) =>
    Object.values(data).find(el => el.userId == id)

console.log(findById(data, 'userId4'));
console.log(findById(data, 'userId2'));
```

Comment: в таком случае будет имя выводиться только для того с каким мы сравниваем  el.userId == 'userId4', а как сделать что бы имя выводилось для всех динамически?

Comment: @dev_jun поправил

Comment: а возможно как нибутдь место одного свойства объекта вернуть другое того же объекта?
Наверное странный вопрос, но все же мб Вы знаете, заранее спасибо)

Comment: @dev_jun а вы попробуйте немного подумать, на основе того кода, что я написал) На основании его можно понять, как получить доступ к св-вам объета

Comment: да, к свойствам я понимаю как получить доступ, но у меня в реакте просто нужно показывать в таблице имена людей, а в наличии есть только userId, и в случае когда приходит не тот userId, который я передал через атрибут то отрисовываеться undefined вместо имени

Comment: как можно передавать в функцию 'userId', а получать id объекта в каком находиться 'userId' ('id..') - это был бы идеальный вариант